# FILE * creation error: Unhandled exception (ucrtbased.dll) Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, c

I'm working with a simple fopen, fwrite, fflush, fclose body of code. For some reason, however, every time I try to create a `FILE *` object, it crashes. My code is below.

```
//fopen
FILE * f_data = fopen("out.txt", 'wb'); // BREAKS HERE
if (f_data == NULL) { printf("fopen failed!"); }

//fwrite
int fwritten = fwrite(data, 1, content_length, f_data);
if (fwritten == 0) { printf("fwrite failed!"); }

//fflush
int flush = fflush(f_data);
if (flush != 0) { printf("fflush failed!"); }

//fclose
int close = fclose(f_data);
if (close != 0) { printf("fclose failed!"); }
```

Whenever I run this code, I get the following error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x5F52C795 (ucrtbased.dll) in main.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00007762.

I've been researching this problem for about an hour now, to no avail. I've learned that this is Windows telling me I've encountered a segmentation fault, possibly from trying to dereference a `NULL` pointer.

If anybody has some insight on why my File * instantiation won't work, please share!

EDIT: I'm not sure it's relevant to this question but the `data` buffer being written is a simple string: "Hello, world, and all who inhabit it!" and `content_length` is set to `sizeof(data)`.

Comment: `'wb'` --> `"wb"`

Comment: ffs. Thank you. I'll show myself out now.

Comment: Pay attention to the compiler warnings — it was trying to tell you what was wrong but you (apparently) were not listening.

Comment: Could you point out which compiler warnings you mean? I'm not sure what warnings were immediately pointing to that problem.

Comment: Today I learned that this compiles:  `int main(void) { printf("%c\n", 'wb'); return 0; }`.   gcc warns `warning: multi-character character constant`, but I had no idea a multi-character character constant was even a thing.

Comment: On a system with GCC (the GNU C Compiler), the line `FILE * f_data = fopen("out.txt", 'wb');` generates two separate warnings: `warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]` and `warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fopen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`.  I'd expect at least the equivalent of the second warning from any competent compiler. Which system are you running on? Which compiler and IDE? What compilation warnings did it give for the code you showed? You might also note that you continue to use the null pointer if `fopen()` fails — not a good idea.

Comment: WRT your edit: `sizeof(data)` will probably not give you what you want, as it will likely return 8 (or whatever the size of a pointer is on your system). `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time to the size of the type you pass it, not the size of the underlying array.

Comment: See delcaration of fopen:
FILE *fopen ( const char * filename, **const char * mode**);

You passed 'wb' (single qoutes), which is char. As already stated by BLUEPIXY, you must pass "wb" (double quotes)